# Find sum of array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I am trying to find the sum of the array, but code is putting all the numbers together, but not adding them for sum. Like, if i have grades of 90, 95, 100, sum will be 09590100. The first FOR loop is tested and works fine to push the grades into an array, but the second for loop is proving to be wrong somewhere.

```
var numOfGrades = prompt("How many total assignments?");
var grades = [];
var sum = 0;
var grade = 0;
var avg = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++) {
    grade = prompt("Type in score");
    grades.push(grade);

}

for (var j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) {
    sum += grades[j];
}

avg = (sum / grades.length)
```

Comment: Use some type conversion using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, you might be having strings in arrays thats getting cancatenated

Comment: Because `prompt()` returns a string. Try `grade = +prompt("Type in score");` instead -- the prefix + operator converts its string argument to a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is that you are reading your input in as a string - you need to parse it as a number

https://www.google.ca/search?q=javascript+convert+string+to+integer

```
for (var i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++) {
    grade = prompt("Type in score");
    grades.push(parseInt(grade));

}
```

Comment: don't `parseInt()` without an explicit radix.

Comment: Yes - more research needs to be done regarding what the op wants as a number

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the parseInt function.  Javascript will treat those grade values as strings.  You need to explicitly make them integers before performing computation on them.  See this example

http://jsfiddle.net/conkman/5Eu7T/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var numOfGrades = prompt("How many total assignments?");
var grades = [];
var sum = 0;
var grade = 0;
var avg = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numOfGrades; i++) {
    grade = prompt("Type in score");
    grades.push(grade);

}

for (var j = 0; j < grades.length; j++) {
    sum += parseInt(grades[j]);
}

avg = (sum / grades.length);
alert(avg);
```

});

Documentation around parseInt:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp